# Clearing history in rhapsody

Tags: rhapsody

Is there a way in rhapsody to clear the history of a state upon a certain event?
I want my states to normally have a certain history, but when leaving the outer state and coming back i want to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much checking, seems the answer is "No".